# Joining Tables in ArcGIS Pro results in majority <null> values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, attribute-joins

The goal is to try to join a table with calculated fields (produced in ArcGIS Pro) with the attribute table of a shapefile. Trying to join them with the common "APN_8" Field, both text, 8 characters. Every time I try to join the table it results in 99% null values. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. It's not a perfect one-to-one but that should mean the inverse, way less null values than joins.

Why am I only getting 127 one-to-one joins when 99% of the records have a matching APN8 number to join to?

It should be almost 1800 joins.

It may have something to do with it being a standalone table. If I reverse the join - as in adding the shapefiles attributes to the standalone table the join works. Also, if I try to join the attribute table from a shapefile to shapefile it works.

**Tables to join:**

[image]

**Join + Validation:**

[image]

**Result (all null except 127 records):**

[image]

Comment: If you use the Join Field tool to permanently join the join table to the input table (or a temp copy for testing), do you get expected results? I stopped using Add Join because it was unreliable (way back in Pro 2.3) but haven't gone back to it.

Comment: @user2856 Unfortunately I get the same results. I think the problem is with it being a stand alone table. Joining other shapefiles' attribute tables appears to not be an issue.

Comment: Check for white spaces at the end of common field.  Rstrip them

Comment: @FelixIP Is it even possible to have whitespace when it's limited to 8 characters and every entry is 8 characters?

Comment: Try to add single record to table and populate relevant field with "ABC".